# Can we segregate gibberish from meaningful sentences just by looking at the features of the 512 dimensional Universal Sentence Encoder Vector?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

Universal Sentence Encoder encodes sentences into a vector of 512 features. My proposition is that if a sentence is gibberish then most of the features will be very close to zero. However, if a sentence has meaning then some of the features out of the 512 features would be much greater than or much lesser than zero. Can we then, just by seeing the vector feature's weight distribution decide which vector encodes meaning and which vector encodes gibberish ?

Comment: This sounds like something you should try to test experimentally: are the vectors which result from 'real' sentences very different, in magnitude or other ways, from various kinds of gibberish? Especially interesting would be to test: (1) reshuffles of real sentences; (2) random word draws from a uniform distribution of all words; (3) random word draws using the real word frequencies; (4) markov chain outputs (which can often seem sensible for short ranges).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the USE encodes features in a very arbitrary fashion. I conducted a lot of experiments and saw that the features scaled up and down in an arbitrary fashion without regard to the sentence being gibberish or meaningful. The experiments include counting the number of positives and negative features in a meaningful and gibberish vector, finding the mean and standard distribution of the features. But nothing bore any pattern which can delineate the two.Attached are the screenshots.

[image: Below is the feature distribution for gibberish sentence vector and meaningful sentence vector]

Below is sample 2 . Many more samples (around 30) were taken and no pattern in count of positive-negative features, standard dev and mean was observed which can separate a gibberish USE vector from a meaningful one.
[image: Sample]

Comment: Dense embeddings like these don't encode easily-interpretable facets into single dimensions, or any certain dimension's direction (positive or negative). Rather, any meaning that is there is in other neighborhoods & oblique directions. So, you'd be unlikely to see patterns in your coarse histograms. Did you evaluate the accuracy of sophisticated classifiers, trained on a large set of labeled meaningful & gibberish sentences? That's the way to know if this feature-extraction method (USE) is helpful for this task.

Comment: (Also, I'm surprised you meant 'gibberish' as total random-letter-noise - per suggestions in my previous comment, I'd assumed you meant real words in nonsense orders! That'd be worth testing, too.)